# How to access parent class instance method from child class static method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class P(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Parent')

    @staticmethod
    def M1():
        print('parent Static')

    @classmethod
    def M2(cls):
        print('parent class method')

    def M3(self):
        print('Instance Method')


class Q(P):

    @staticmethod
    def W1():
       super(Q,Q).M3()##Here I am getting error

Q.W1()
```

> TypeError: unbound method M3() must be called with Q instance as first
>   argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: This isn't python3 by looks of it, you are using print without parenthesis, please mark as python2.x or update the question to reflect proper python3.

Comment: You don't have an instance to call `M3` on. Why would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P.M3` is not static or a class method.

Notice the `self` in the signature of the method:

```
def M3(self):
```

There is no way you can call it from W1 without having an instance of a P object.

What you are trying to do it similar to `P.M3()` and that will not work.

From a Q `staticmethod`, you can call other static/class methods in your base class, however, to call an instance method you need an `instance`. A static method in Q does not provide an instance, so it will be unable to call instance methods in the base class.

There are many ways that you could use to call M3 but they will depend on what you really need. For instance:

```
class Q(P):
    @staticmethod
    def W1():
        p = P()
        p.M3()

    @staticmethod
    def W2(p):
        p.M3()


Q.W1()

some_p = P()
Q.W2(some_p)

some_q = Q()
Q.W2(some_q)
```

Comment: if i will call M1() and M2() in same way thn i am getting output , But dont know whether my qns is correct or not . Or Is there any way to call M3()?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can call M1() and M2() but to call M3() you need an instance, and W1 does not have access to one because is a static method.